# Open file dialog for pandas dataframe within tkinter app

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python so hoping this isn't a bad question. I wrote a script to trim down a very large csv to a usable file for report purposes. The script works well, but i'd like to apply this to a windows app using tkinter. I'm having a hard time figuring out if you can define a pandas dataframe from an open file diaglog within tkinter (prompts user for file and location instead of hard coding the file location).

I'm also interested if I can have a user input box to provide a text value for filtering the data. (Ex. If a user enters "CA" it will filter the column for State = "CA".

Below is my full script that i'm trying to apply to a tkinter app.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as xl

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()

# DataFrame 1 Can this be changed to a button with askopenfilename for Tkinter App?
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'G:\1GEO\GiganticFile.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# DataFrame 2 Can this be changed to a button with askopenfileneame for Tkinter App?
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'G:\1GEO\FIPS LU.csv')

# Change DF2 FIPS & DF1 BlockCode column to string, create block length field
df2['FIPS']=df2['FIPS'].apply(str)
df1['Block_LEN'] = df1['BlockCode'].apply(len)
df1['BlockCode']=df1['BlockCode'].apply(str)

#Slice based on character length of BlockCode field
df1.loc[df1['Block_LEN'] == 15, 'FIPS'] = df1['BlockCode'].str.slice(0,5)
df1.loc[df1['Block_LEN'] == 14, 'FIPS'] = df1['BlockCode'].str.slice(0,4)

# Create DataFrame 3 from merging DF1 & DF2
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='FIPS', how ='inner')

# Filter on State & County Name, Can these two fields be user input fields in the Tkinter App?
County_Results = df3[(df3['StateAbbr']=='CA') & (df3['County Name']=='Modoc')]

# Print head for testing purpose, replace with Excel Export on finalizing App
County_Results.head()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes, you can do that, but what have you tried? you would need some kind of a trigger like a button, that will call a function, which will then open the filedialog and ask the user for the file, when user chooses it, you will get back the file path (or file depending on what you need/want), then you can save that path in a global variable or immediately do sth with it